# How to properly configure iptables with wireguard?

Tags: iptables, wireguard

I have two vms (server,client) connected to the network 10.0.0.0/24 and running wireguard, the server has the following config

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <server_private_key>
Address = 172.0.0.1/24 
ListenPort = 10001

[Peer]
PublicKey = <client_public_key>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 10
```

the server iptables rules

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

the client has the following config

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <client_private_key>
Address = 172.0.0.2/24 

[Peer]
PublicKey = <server_public_key>
AllowedIPs = 172.0.0.0/24
Endpoint = 172.0.0.1:10001 
PersistentKeepalive = 10
```

and the client iptables rules

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

when pining the client `172.0.0.2` I get the following output

```
PING 172.0.0.2 (172.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Destination address required
From 172.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Destination address required
From 172.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Destination address required
^C
--- 172.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2045ms
```

and when pinging the server `172.0.0.1` all packets are dropped

```
PING 172.0.0.1 (172.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 172.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2053ms
```

Comment: your problem is the `Endpoint` - which would never be the servers wireguard ip address, it would be the ip address of the server itself - if you checked the status of wireguard, you'd see that nothing is connected